# How to use jwtToken in the communication via socket.io?

Tags: angular, socket.io, jwt

I want to communication angular and nodejs-express via socket.io 
what is the best way to verify user authentification?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        let jwt = socket.token;
        //to Implement
        let isAuth = authService.verifyToken(jwt);
         if (!isAuth) {
           socket.disconnect()
           }

    });
```

is that a good way ?

Answer (score 0):

you can put your JWT in an HttpOnly Cookie (it is raccomanded),

this cookie will be automatically send by the browser in the first http/s connection,

then on Server side you could do:

this to set up the cookie

```
_res.cookie('JWT', jwtBearerToken, { maxAge: expireMilliseconds, httpOnly: true})
```

and then

```
function async verifyToken(_socket: Socket, _next: NextFunction) {

    let xsrfToken = _socket.handshake.headers['x-xsrf-token'];
    var cookie = _socket.request.headers.cookie
    if (_socket.request.headers.cookie && xsrfToken) {

      let token = parseCookie(cookie);
      let decodedJWT: any;

      try {
      //using jsonwebtoken library
        decodedJWT = await 
   jwt.verify(token.JWT, this.RSA_PUBLIC_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'], });


      } catch (err) {
        //do something

        return;
      }
      _next();
    }

  }
```

and "use" this function on socket-server like

```
io.use((socket, next) => this.verifyToken(socket,next));
```

[Socke.io namespace.use(fn) API](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn)

Comment: and how append the token at the angular side?

Comment: You don't you append the token in the cookie but server side. The browser will send it for you

Comment: here you can find info of how to set cookies https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful way to do that using **socketio-jwt**

```
var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

var io = socketIo.listen(server);

io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: 'YOUR-SECRET',
  handshake: true
}));
```

and at the the front side : `this.socket = io(URLS.BASE_URL,{
        query: 'token=' + localStorage.getItem('my-token')
      });`

we suppose that the jwt token is stored in the local storage.